# How can i read a textfield data from a client side to server side textfield javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to send input from client TextField to a server TextField and read some outputs back to client-side TextFields instead of Textarea. how can I read a value in the text field instead of TextArea? can someone please help me with a simple example?

Comment: You should really be parametrising your queries. What you have there looks very open to Injection; that's a if security flaw

Comment: I have no idea what does that means? I am very new to the programming field.

Comment: [SQL Injection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (I still don't understand why people aren't taught about injection; it's like not teaching people how to use the brakes when learning to drive...)

Comment: ??? Getting the text works pretty much the same for `TextField` and `TextArea`. What exactly is the issue with doing this? As for communication with a server: This entirely depends on the protocol. Answering a question that is this broad is out of the scope of an answer.